# How to write in a single file with multiple threads?

Tags: c#, multithreading, file-io

I am creating Windows Application in C# in which I want to write in multiple files with multiple threads. I am getting data from different ports and there is one file associated with every port. Is it possible that creation of thread for every port and use the same thread again and again for writing data to respective file? 
Suppose I am getting data from ports 10000,10001,10002 and there are three files as 10000.txt, 10001.txt and 10002.txt. I have to create three threads for writing data to these three files respectively and I want to use these threads again and again. Is it possible? Please can you give a small sample of code if possible?

Comment: you need to either serialize the file access (for example by a Mutex or similar) or have one central thread responsible for writing the file which every other thread just tells what to write (queue the work to be done by that central thread)...

Comment: Why do you need to write to a single file from multiple threads? This is a bad idea, not just from a synchronisation but even the mechanics of writing to the file (locks etc).

Comment: Here i am getting data from different ports continuously and there  are different files.Three is one file associated with single port.I want to write that data coming from a port to respective file.I want to create thread for every incoming data ,It will write that data to particular file and abort it and so on.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7733619/filestream-beginwrite-advantages-over-filestream-write?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this is asking for trouble.

So, you need to have a thread-safe writer class:

```
public class FileWriter
{
    private ReaderWriterLockSlim lock_ = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();
    public void WriteData(/*....whatever */)
    {
        lock_.EnterWriteLock();
        try
        {
            // write your data here
        }
        finally
        {
            lock_.ExitWriteLock();
        }
    }

} // eo class FileWriter
```

This is suitable for being called by many threads.  BUT, there's a caveat.  There may well be lock contention.  I used a `ReadWriterLockSlim` class, because you may want to do read locks as well and hell, that class allows you to upgrade from a read state also.

Comment: Thanks for response, i written only one method for writing to the file and i am passing only different parameters for that method.But if i use LOCK to the writing method then only one thread can access that method.This is not any use of me.

Comment: @Dany, multiple threads plus + 1 file = bad news.  What is your use case?

Comment: multiple threads plus + 1 file is not my case.My case is multiple threads and multiple files.

Comment: >> ReaderWriterLockSlimlock  - is it a typo?

Comment: @Konstantin, looks like the guy who correct the class name messed it up - will edit :)

Answer (score 4):

You answers to other posts are somewhat out-of-line with your original question - it seems you want to write to one different file per thread.

The easy answer is.. just do it - the file system is thread-safe.  The only snag may be performance with only one disk.  Concurrently and rapidly writing small chunks of data to many files may result in a lot of disk-thrashing as the file system tries to cope with the distributed files/directories with only one rotor arm.  Modern hard disks with large caches and clever controllers will mitigate this to some extent, but you may have an issue.  Try it and see!

Your problems will be increased if you plan to continually create and destroy threads, open and close data files for every incoming network read.  If you can possibly avoid this, do so.

If the disk cannot keep up, you could implement some clever 'lazy-writing' algorithm of your own to increase the size of the disk writes and so reduce the number, or buy an SSD, or both.

Answer (score 0):

You'l need to serialize  the threads and manage the closing and opening file calls. And probably use append instead of write.. You could use a thread manager class( more like the main thread) to helping syncing all your other threads.
Though the best thing would probably be to use one thread dedicated for writing to that file..

Comment: Thanks for response but can i create one dedicated thread for one particular file and another thread for another file and so on?

Comment: @Dany - Unless you have a thread that is always running the same thread is going to handle writting to any of your files.  Even the accepted answer is not going to spawn a new thread to write to the file, only prevent multiple threads, from writting to the same file at the sametime.