# How to write in a multiple file with multiple threads?

Tags: c#, multithreading, file-io

i am creating windows application in C# in which i want to write in a multiple file with multiple threads.I am getting data from different ports and there is one file associated with every port.Is it possible that creation of thread for every port and use the same thread again and again for writing data to respective file? Suppose i am getting data from ports 10000,10001,10002 and there are three files as 10000.txt,10001.txt and 10002.txt. I have to create three threads for writing data to these three files respectively and i want to use these threads again and again.Is it possible?Please can you give a small sample of code if possible?

Comment: EXACT, char for char duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/8035029/331508, except for the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you let each thread handle its own file it'll do?

So when a port reader thread is created, you open the file that belongs to that port, and store the handle to that file. Whenever you receive data, you write it to the file:

```
class PortReader
{
    StreamWriter _writer;
    int _port;
    YourPort _myPort;

    public PortReader(int port)
    {
        // Do your port initialization stuff

        _writer = new StreamWriter(port + ".txt");
    }

    private void DataReceived(String data)
    {
        _writer.WriteLine(data);
    }

    public void StartReading()
    {
        while (_myPort.Connected)
        {
            // Do your port reading stuff
            String data = _myPort.ReadData();

            // Do some processing with the data

            // And now let it be written to the file
            DataReceived(data);
        }
    }
}
```

And then start them like such:

```
List<PortReader> readerList = new List<PortReader>();

readerList.Add(new PortReader(10000));
readerList.Add(new PortReader(10001));
readerList.Add(new PortReader(10002));
// etc...

foreach (PortReader reader in readerList)
{
    new Thread(new ThreadStart(reader.StartReading)).Start();
}
```

Ideally you want to separate the file writing from the port reading, but I'll leave that up to you for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: I don't see how this reuses the threads... you have no loops.

Comment: I think OP doesn't need to reuse threads. And what use is that? You might as well execute it without threads in a single loop.

Comment: Yeah you could, but then you would need to use select. If there are few threads, it's an intuitive way to solve the problem.

Comment: I want to write the data again and again because i am getting data continuously. So How i can do that in above program?

Comment: @Tudor I don't know what you mean. And to OP, in StartReading you start ... reading, and every time you receive data you call DataReceived. The method StartReading could contain something like `while (_myPort.Connected) { DataReceived(_myPort.ReadData()) } `, so it stays in there as long as you're connected.

Comment: Suppose i got data from 10000 port and my thread is writing that to 10000.txt file and before completion of writing operation if data comes from same port again (from 10000) port then what will be the output?because the file is already in writing mode?

Comment: That's impossible, since `WriteLine` is blocking. If you want the port reading and the file writing on different threads and/or to be non-blocking you'd have to add some buffering and cross-thread communication.

Comment: Can i sleep the new incoming thread upto the completion of current thread writing opeartion?Is it working or not?Please give me solution.

Comment: @Dany why isn't doing a loop in each thread and reading and then writing to a file a solution?

Comment: How would I know? It's your ports, your code, you can test it. This **is** a solution, you just have to fit it into your situation. For the record: when the thread for port 10000 is writing data, the thread for port 10001 can still receive data.

Answer (score 1):

```
var ports = new List<int> { 1000, 1001, 1002 };

Parallel.ForEach(ports, p =>
{
    var data = GetDataForPort(p);
    var path = string.Format(@"C:\{0}.txt", p);

    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(path))
        writer.Write(data);
});
```