# c# multiple threads writing to the same file

Tags: c#

I have a multithreading application which write to the same file on a specific **event** .
how can i lock the file and make the thread wait until its free ?
i can't use [FileStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream(v=vs.110).aspx) since it will throw exception on the other threads (can't acces)

```
FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.Read);
```

is there any proper way to do this ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [write in a single file with multiple threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8035029/how-to-write-in-a-single-file-with-multiple-threads)

Answer (score 14):

You need a thread-safe filewriter to manage threads. You can use `ReaderWriterLockSlim` to perform it.

```
public class FileWriter
{
    private static ReaderWriterLockSlim lock_ = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();
    public void WriteData(string dataWh,string filePath)
    {
        lock_.EnterWriteLock();
        try
        {
            using (var fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
            {
                byte[] dataAsByteArray = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes(dataWh);
                fs.Write(dataAsByteArray, 0, dataWh.Length);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            lock_.ExitWriteLock();
        }
    }
}
```

**Example;**

```
Parallel.For(0, 100, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10 },i =>
{
   new FileWriter().WriteData("Sample Data", Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,"SampleFile.txt"));
});
```

Comment: I had to add fs.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.End); before the GetBytes line to keep the code from overwriting text.