# Reading large files in bytes

Tags: c#, filestream

EDIT:

As per the suggestion, I have started to implement the following:

```
 private string Reading (string filePath)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[100000];

        FileStream strm = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read,
        FileShare.Read, 1024, FileOptions.Asynchronous);

        // Make the asynchronous call
        IAsyncResult result = strm.BeginRead(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, new 
        AsyncCallback(CompleteRead), strm);

    }

       private void CompleteRead(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        FileStream strm = (FileStream)result.AsyncState;

        strm.Close();
    }
```

How do I go about actually returning the data that I've read?

Comment: It is recommended to use `Asynchronous I/O` when dealing with large files. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kztecsys.aspx

Comment: Also, read this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7733619/filestream-beginwrite-advantages-over-filestream-write

Comment: extending netscape,beginread method is what you should be looking at.

Comment: side note: in this code, you use a for loop, but you make no use of i. Maybe just use while( (hexInt = fs.ReadByte()) != -1) ?

Comment: @NETscape Can you take a look at my edit?

Comment: @terrybozzio How do I actually get the data from the file i'm reading?

Comment: it looks like this will answer your question: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iasyncresult.asyncwaithandle.aspx

Comment: @NETscape I'm still lost. The AsyncMethodCaller doesn't even accept an argument like it does in the example code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static byte[] myarray;

static void Main(string[] args)
{

    FileStream strm = new FileStream(@"some.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read,
        FileShare.Read, 1024, FileOptions.Asynchronous);

    myarray = new byte[strm.Length];
    IAsyncResult result = strm.BeginRead(myarray, 0, myarray.Length, new
    AsyncCallback(CompleteRead),strm );
    Console.ReadKey();
}

    private static void CompleteRead(IAsyncResult result)
    {
          FileStream strm = (FileStream)result.AsyncState;
          int size = strm.EndRead(result);

          strm.Close();
          //this is an example how to read data.
          Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(myarray, 0, size));
    }
```

It should not read "Random",it reads in the same order but just in case try this:

```
Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(myarray));
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It seems to be reading the data in a random order. Is there a way I can stop that from happening?

Comment: what do you mean random order? Is `BitConverter` turning your data into big or little endian, making it looked messed up, but isn't?

Answer (score 1):

```
private static byte[] buffer = new byte[100000];

private string ReadFile(string filePath)
{
    FileStream strm = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read,
    FileShare.Read, 1024, FileOptions.Asynchronous);

    // Make the asynchronous call
    IAsyncResult result = strm.BeginRead(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, new 
    AsyncCallback(CompleteRead), strm);

    //AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne tells you when the operation is complete
    result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();

    //After completion, your know your data is in your buffer
    Console.WriteLine(buffer);

    //Close the handle
    result.AsyncWaitHandle.Close();
}

private void CompleteRead(IAsyncResult result)
{
    FileStream strm = (FileStream)result.AsyncState;
    int size = strm.EndRead(result);

    strm.Close();
}
```

Comment: using `strm.Length` to set the buffer like in terrys answer would be better, otherwise its going to try and read 1000000 bytes before finishing I believe.