# Signing Data Using C#

Tags: c#, rsa, digital-signature, sha256

I have file which I am signing using RSA algorithm using two methods:

1. bouncycastle
2. openssl

both results in two different output and openssl results in valid file. I don't know why my c# code is giving wrong output.

Here is my code for bouncy castle in c#

```
    private void GenerateSignatureFile(string sourceFile)
    {
        try
        {
            var stringToSign = ReadText(sourceFile).ToString();                
            var sig = Sign(stringToSign);                
            var fileContent = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(sig);
            using (var sw = File.CreateText(Path.Combine(_projectLocation, _sigFileName)))
            {
                sw.WriteLine(fileContent);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LoggingService.Log(ex.Message);
        }
    }


    public byte[] Sign(String data)
    {
        var key = readPrivateKey();
        /* Make the key */
        var keyParameter = new RsaKeyParameters(key.IsPrivate, ((RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters)key).Modulus, ((RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters)key).Exponent);

        /* Init alg */
        ISigner sig = SignerUtilities.GetSigner("SHA256withRSA");

        /* Populate key */
        sig.Init(true, key);

        /* Get the bytes to be signed from the string */
        var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);

        /* Calc the signature */
        sig.BlockUpdate(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        return sig.GenerateSignature();
    }

    public static IEnumerable<string> ReadText(string scriptPath)
    {
        var buffer = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(scriptPath))
        {
            if (line == "GO")
            {
                yield return buffer.ToString();
                buffer.Clear();
            }
            else
            {
                buffer.AppendLine(line);
            }
        }
    }

  private AsymmetricKeyParameter readPrivateKey()
    {
        AsymmetricCipherKeyPair keyPair;

        using (var reader = new StringReader(_privateKey))
            keyPair = (AsymmetricCipherKeyPair)new PemReader(reader).ReadObject();

        return keyPair.Private;
    }
```

and in openssl I use following command to sign data

```
openssl dgst -sha256 -sign content_private_key.pem -out content.zip.sig content.zip
```

I don't know why my c# code is resulting in different output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that `ReadText` will always return the text identical to the binary text that `openssl` processes. To be sure, just write the `bytes` variable to file after the following line was executed:

```
var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
```

For instance you could compare the two files using `sha256sum`.

If this is indeed the culprit then simply read in the file as binary and sign that.

Comment: Thanks @Maarten. yes you are right ReadText() is the culprit. but now I'm facing another issue with signing large file while converting it to byte array (throws outOfMemoryException). I have gone through with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17618925/reading-large-files-in-bytes but it didn't work. Do you have any idea how i can acheive it in bouncy castle.